# TypeScript angular 1.5 WebPack and code splitting sytem.import

Tags: typescript2.0, webpack-2, code-splitting

I'm trying to get code splitting configured with

- angular 1.5
- typescript 2.x
- webpack 2

Basic setup: I use vscode typescript compiler to compile ts files to an output folder with same folder structure as source folder.

```
\common
  myservice.ts
\testapp
  pageonecomp.ts
  pagetwocomp.ts
  testapp.ts
```

webpack entry point is testapp\testapp.js which contains

```
System.import('../common/myservice').then((myservice)=>{
    angular.module('testapp',['myservice'])
       .component( ... )
       .component( ... )
});
```

and for the moment, nor pageonecomp.ts neither pagetwocomp.ts use anything from myservice.ts. When I compile and than run webpack 2, it shows :

```
                  Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
      0.bundle.js  1.17 kB       0  emitted
testapp.bundle.js  8.74 kB       1  emitted  testapp
```

which is exactly what I want, 0.bundle.js contains MyService, testapp.bundle.js contains pageonecomp, pagetwocomp and testapp angular module.

But now I want to use MyService type which is exported from myservice.ts inside pageonecomp.ts. In order for typescript to be able to provide code completion on MyService class, I need to import MyService type in pageonecomp.ts :

```
import {MyService} from '../common/myservice';

class PageOneComp {
  static $inject=['myservice'];
  constructor(private myservice:MyService) {}
  doSomething() { myservice.doSomething(); } // intellisense works
}
```

But when I run webpack now, code splitting does not work anymore, as you can see from the output:

```
            Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   testapp.bundle.js  7.53 kB       0  [emitted]  testapp
```

MyService class in now included in the testapp bundle, which I don't want...

Does anyone know how to make this working ? The goal is to have webpack create my bundles solely based on the import statements to determine what should go in the bunldles,  and System.import to specify where code splitting should occur.

Note: for the moment I do NOT need dynamic loading of additional angular modules, I'm just trying to make bundles for multiple entry points (multiple small spa's), and several common bundles shared between those spa's.